# Taxonomy Term header image

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I created a field for taxonomy terms called "Category Image". I am overriding the taxonomy term pages `/taxonomy/term/%` using views. The only way to add the "Category Image" on top of a page is to add the relationship **Content: Taxonomy terms on node** so I can have the category image field that I produce excluded from display and rewrite it on the header.

The problem with this solution is that I have multiple duplicates on my term page's nodes.

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Is the field on the term itself?

Comment: Yes, the field is on the term itself. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display has the option to render the term in a certain view mode and then render a view below it. You should check it out.